# How to receive data in real time from TCP socket using PHP or JS?

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, tcp, real-time

I have a TCP socket server that sends data to all clients that are connected.

The server sends new data every 2 seconds.

I need to display the data from this server in web page and update it as soon as it changes or every 2 seconds.

I sure can store this data in a database and call AJAX every 2 seconds to update it.

But is there a way to fetch and display data in real time?

Comment: Websockets or [Socket.io](http://socket.io) presumably.

Comment: I solved it by using https://github.com/playay/ws2s 
Perfect for the job, just the thing I needed